# Filter contacts in iphone address book

Tags: iphone, addressbook, nspredicate

I've created an address book copy with

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(
                                                           kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                           CFArrayGetCount(people),
                                                           people
                                                           );
```

now i would have just people with an address set in.

I've tried filtering with NSPredicate, but I don't know how to use the predicateWithFormat correctly with address book constants.
This doesn't work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ like %@)", kABPersonFirstNameProperty, aVariable];
```

Can someone suggest me something?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at http://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper -- if it doesn't have code that does what you want already, it should be a useful guide for writing it yourself.