# Accessing list of persons with email address from iPhone address book

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I want to display list of people in the iPhone's address book with atleast one email address. Can someone please explain how can I filter this using the AddressBook framework?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9530-filtering-address-book.html#post42386) (it's your question exactly)

and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697210/filter-contacts-in-iphone-address-book)

which references [Erica Sadun's ABContactHelper](http://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper)

It looks like the first link has the code worked out, though there was mention of an arrayIndexOutOfBounds exception (which shouldn't be too hard to debug).